# Pass input from FXML text field to BCrypt.checkpassword

Tags: java, fxml, bcrypt

I am having a first crack at both FXML and BCrypt as a learning exercise.

I have two text fields in my FXML and my plan was to concatinate them in a string to compare to the hash from Bcrypt.

This is my example.fxml

```
<TextField fx:id="userId" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="56.0" onAction="#loginpressed"/>
<PasswordField fx:id="passwordfield" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="111.0" onAction="#loginpressed"/>
```

This is my LoginPage.java

```
private void loginpressed(ActionEvent event) 
 {

    if (BCrypt.checkpw((unpwfield), passwordhash))
        System.out.println("Accepted");
    else
        System.out.println("Denied");

 }
```

I thought my answer would be

```
private String unpwfield = userId+passwordfield;
```

but it doesnt work. (The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) javafx.scene.control.TextField, javafx.scene.control.TextField) why?

**EDIT**

I have also tried to do the following which gives a Nullpointer

```
String unpwfield;
    unpwfield = userId.getText()+passwordfield.getText();
    if (BCrypt.checkpw(unpwfield, passwordhash))
        System.out.println("It matches");
    else
        System.out.println(userId.getText()+passwordfield.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn out the code is correct.  I hadnt injected the  `@FXML passwordfield`